# Convert string to objectId in MongoDB 3.4

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

I need to convert string to objectId in mongoDB, in mongodb 4 it can be achieved through `$toObjectId": "$bar_id`

But the problem is my mongodb version is `3.4` 
Is there any way to achieve that in version 3.4?
Upgrading isn't an option since it's used in production env

The use case is I need to do lookup from one collection to another, the collection looks like

Collection F:

```
{ 
    "_id" : ObjectId("a"), 
    "field" : "some-field", 
    "cityId" : "cityId", 
    "regionId" : "regionId", 
    "countryId" : "countryId", 
}
```

and collection country looks like (region and city is similar)

```
{ 
    "_id" : ObjectId("countryId"), 
    "name": "someName"
}
```

I tried using query:

```
db.F.aggregate([
   {
     $lookup:
       {
         from: "country",
         localField: "countryId",
         foreignField: "_id",
         as: "country"
       }
  }
])
```

but the result looks like:

```
{ 
    "_id" : ObjectId("a"), 
    "field" : "some-field", 
    "cityId" : "cityId", 
    "regionId" : "regionId", 
    "countryId" : "countryId", 
    "country" : [

    ]
}
```

Any advice?

Thank you

Comment: In MongoDB you don't have any option to do this unless you upgrade to 4 or greater, or you need to do updates on all docs, What programming language do you use ?

Comment: I use java, but this is just to pull query from data not to be used in application ...

Comment: Then I would say you might not any option other than upgrade or updates to doc..